# Create an ItemGroup by Batching Another ItemGroup

Tags: msbuild

I need to look up files based on a dynamic set of directories. Here is my shared build script:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <LookupDirs Include="F:\Dir1" />
    <LookupDirs Include="F:\Dir2" />
    <LookupDirs Include="F:\Dir3" />
    <LookupDirs Include="@(AdditionalLookupDirs)" />
</ItemGroup>

<!-- This doesn't work. -->
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="%(LookupDirs.Identity)\*.ext" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="FilesByBatchingLookupDirs">
    <Message Text="Files: %(Files.Identity)" />

    <!-- This works. --->
    <ItemGroup>
        <TargetFiles Include="%(LookupDirs.Identity)\*.ext" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Message Text="TargetFiles: %(TargetFiles.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

The intention is to let people using the build script specify their own custom lookup directories via the `AdditionalLookupDirs` item group, then batch on the lookup directories to find a set of files.

I'd prefer it if the `Files` item group was outside a target, so I can simply authoring and don't have to remember to call the target which creates the `Files` item group. Unfortunately, it looks like this is impossible.  I've only been able to create the `Files` item group by batching the `LookupDirs` item group in a `Target`.

**Is it possible to create a new item group by batching on an existin item group outside a `Target`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't believe you can, but you can use `InitialTargets`. I usually have an `Init` target cause one can't add "global" metadata outside of a target either or do more advanced or delayed data input.

```
<Project InitialTargets="Init;FilesByBatchingLookupDirs" DefaultTargets="Foo" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <LookupDir Include="$(ProgramW6432)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn" />
        <LookupDir Include="$(ProgramW6432)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn" />
        <LookupDir Include="$(ProgramW6432)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Init">
        <ItemGroup>
            <LookupDir>
                <Foo>Bar</Foo>
            </LookupDir>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Message Text="%(LookupDir.Identity) %(Foo)" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="FilesByBatchingLookupDirs">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Files Include="%(LookupDir.FullPath)\**\*.exe" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>

    <Target Name="Foo" DependsOnTargets="FilesByBatchingLookupDirs">
        <Message Text="%(Files.Identity)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```