# csproj include (recursive) folders based on a list (batching)

Tags: msbuild, csproj

I want to add some files recursively to a single project that are located in folders inside my solution root.

Right now, I found a working solution to add those files by specifying each folder manually:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Folder1\**\*">
        <Link>Folder1\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\Folder2\**\*">
        <Link>Folder2\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\Folder3\**\*">
        <Link>Folder3\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

As those can be a handfull folders and they can be different depending on my solution, I want to have an easy list to define the folder names.

Something like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefinedResourceFolders>Folder1;Folder2;Folder3</DefinedResourceFolders>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This would also allow me to input this as a property directly when calling msbuild to *extend* the files that are going to the build output, maybe.
I tried to look into the [MSBuild Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022) documentation and several other online sources, but I could not figure it out. Most batching examples I found were working with Targets, not Includes into the solution items.

Is this possible? How would I define the `<ItemGroup>` for the content then?

---

P.S.: I don't care about wildcard issues with `.csproj` files when new files are added, etc. This will either be a single "Resources" project only containing those displayed files, or I am using my external `.props` file that I am importing into each `.csproj` file anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to include all files in folders `root/Folder1`, `root/Folder2` and `root/Folder3` recursively.

This is how the builds (both VS and CLI) do what you want. However, VS will not show the files as part of the project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" InitialTargets="__AddBatchedContent;$(InitialTargets)">
  <!-- the usual properties -->

  <!-- You could of course define the folder array directly in an Item,
       but this is what you wanted :-) -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Lookups>Folder1;Folder2;Folder3</Lookups>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <LookupDir Include="$(Lookups)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="__AddBatchedContent">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- save the original source folder of the globbed file name in custom
           metadata "Folder" so we can use it later as its output base folder -->
      <__BatchedFiles Include="..\%(LookupDir.Identity)\**\*" Folder="%(LookupDir.Identity)" />
      <Content Include="@(__BatchedFiles)" Link="%(Folder)\%(RecursiveDir)\%(Filename)%(Extension)" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Note that if you want to put this in a .targets file to use this technique in multiple projects, you should replace the `..\` with `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\` so that the path is relative to the (known) location of the .targets file instead of the (unknown) location of the importing project.

Thanks to [@Ilya Kozhevnikov for the basis of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24527843/1767703).

You are not the only one who would like this to be simpler :-): https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3274

Comment: This would work nicely. But not adding the files to the solution explorer does not make them searchable in VS, which is a pity.

I wanted a separate property so I could define the folder list in another `.props` file that might get changed depending on the repository I am working on, while the `.targets` file will be the same for all.

Comment: Concerning the "separate property", there is nothing stopping you from defining the folders as `Item`s of an `ItemGroup` in an external `.props` file. To me that would feel more MSBuild-y and may also play nicer with VCS diffs.

Yes, searchability is a problem. But AFAIK this is unavoidable atm. It is also AFAIK not possible to use globs in the `sln` itself. So you cannot even manually add those files to the solution (for searchability) on a folder level, but would have to sync each and every single one :-/